# Regex remove specific part of a string in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

in a pandas df column I have all records like this:

```
    column
strunk 0  somestring
strunk 0 anotherstring
strunk 0 string
```

How can I remove the `strunk 0` part and keep only the rest?

to get:

```
   column
  somestring
anotherstring
    string
```

Comment: `df["column"] = df["column"].replace("strunk 0\s*", "", regex=True)` ?

Comment: nope.   returns the string with the strunk 0 part

Answer (score 0):

If the part you want to remove is the same in every row you can do:

`df['new_col'] = df['old_col'].str[10:]`

Comment: Empty DataFrame Columns: [column] Index: []

Comment: Can you post a fuller example of your code? The code above doesn't produce an empty dataframe (unless it started that way).